# I have build an Web App on with caching data. But need to delete cached data for every one hour

Tags: javascript, angular, caching

I have build an Web App on with caching data.

Serving that cached data if the page is loading second time with out making any network calls

But Data in the back end refreshes in every one hour.

I want to ignore cache or delete cache for every one hour with out setInterval

```js
private fireAnalyticsGETAPI(methodName, paramString?, serveFromCache?):Observable<any> {

    let pString = paramString ? paramString : AnalyticsDataService.getBaseParamsURL();
    let url = this.getAPIEndpoint() + methodName + encodeURI(pString);

    if(serveFromCache===undefined){
      serveFromCache = true
    }

    //getting the data from cache store
    let cData = this.phenomCacheService.getData(url);

 
    if(serveFromCache===false){
      cData = null;
    }
   // if cache is present serve cache to UI
    if(cData){
      return Observable.create(observer =>
              {
                setTimeout(()=>{
                  return observer.next(cData);
                },10);

              });

    }else{ 
     //If cache is not present fire API to get data serve to UI and store in CACHE
      console.log("Firing API with url :: " + url);
      let authHeaders = this.loginService.getAuthorizationHeaders();
      return this.http.get(url, {
        headers: authHeaders
      }).map((res)=>{
        //setting the data in cache store to use it further cases
        let data = this.extractData(res);
        this.phenomCacheService.setData(url,data);
        return data;
      }).catch((e)=> {
            return this.handleError(e);
          });

    }
  }
```

Comment: Where/what/how exactly are you caching…?

Comment: Caching request and response into an object.